# why the derivative of a conformal mapping must be nonzero?

Tags: complex-analysis

I read that for a conformal map to preserve angles it is required to a have a nonzero derivative. I'm trying to convince myself that this is always true in a simple but detailed way. So far, I've followed the video [Conformal Mapping in Complex Variables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6gFdyqlwWE) and the crucial step around minute 11 is that $arg(\frac {df} {dz_A} ) = arg (\frac {df} {dz_B})$ and it is said that the argument of zero is undefined, so the derivative must be nonzero.

I'm trying to visualize more in detail what is really happening in some simple examples.

Let's say we have to curves $z = t + i t$ and $z = t - i t$ meeting in the origin at an angle of $\frac \pi 2$ in a x-y plane (as usual x it the real part and y the imaginary part).
I can see that applying a map $w = z^2$ they transform into two curves along the positive and negative y axis with a cusp in the origin where the derivative (or the angle) is not defined.
So my understanding is that to represent the transformed curve in the w complex plane we need to invert the f mapping and the new angles are related to the derivative of the inverse function, but the inverse of the derivative is not defined when the derivative is zero and so the angles of the transformed curves (transformed by the mapping $w = f(z)$) represented in the w complex plane have a sort of a discontinuity and therefore I think that those transformed curves have a cusp or their angles are not defined in that point..
Does my reasoning make sense?

Anyway, I can also see that if I transform the two above said curves $z = t + i t$ and $z = t - i t$ by a map $w = f(z) = z^3$ - that should not be conformal at $t = 0$ since $f'(0) = 0$ - nonetheless I get these two graphs from [Wolfram conformal mapping](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20%7BRe%28w%29%2CIm%28w%29%7D%20where%20w%3D%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Az%5E3%2F%2F%5D%20where%20%20z%3D%5B%2F%2Fmath%3At%20-%20i%20t%2F%2F%5D%20where%20t%20from%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A-4%2F%2F%5D%20to%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A4%2F%2F%5D) (follow the link to get the second picture below, for example)

[image]
[image]

Is there something wrong in the way I use the above widget from Wolfram or is it true that in some (even if rare) cases a map with a zero derivative in a certain point can preserve the angle between two curves intersecting at the point?

Comment: Very important that you have actual holomorphic function; by a translation of function, we can say $g(0)=0$   WLOG. Then the Taylor series has a first nonzero term. If this is $a_1 z$  it works. If  the linear coefficient is zero, there is some $k \geq 2$ such that $g(z) = z^k h(z)$  near the origin, where $h(0) = C \neq 0,$ and $g(z) \approx C z^k$  near the origin

Comment: added: the conclusion is that zero derivative implies not injective near the origin

Comment: Found an [interesting explanation](http://reedbeta.com/blog/conformal-texture-mapping/#invertibility-and-critical-points) with the **visualization**: "*In fact, graphing $z^n$ gives you $n$ copies of the plane, squished together into wedges around the origin. All of the copies are conformal mappings—but their scale becomes increasingly extreme as you approach the origin, and the function is not strictly conformal at the origin.*" . I have to study the Shader language to get the correct visual representation, starting from $z^2$ as shown [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdSfWW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:U\subset \Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ a holomorphic function and $z_0\in U$, where $U$ is a region. Suppose $f'(z_0)=0$. This means that

$$\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=0\iff f(z)-f(z_0)\ll z-z_0,$$ as $z\to z_0.$

The final result states that the difference of images of points $z,z_0$ vanishes much faster than the difference of the points, hence the vector $f(z)-f(z_0)$ has an argument in essence undefined relative to $z-z_0$ as $z\to z_0$. Therefore it is impossible for $f'(z_0)$ to rotate $z-z_0$ till $f(z)-f(z_0).$

On the contrary, if $f'(z_0)\neq 0,$ the limit above would equivalently gives

$$f(z)-f(z_0)\sim f'(z_0)(z-z_0),$$ as $z\to z_0,$ which clearly indicates that $f(z)-f(z_0)$ is approximately the rotation of $z-z_0$ at angle $\arg f'(z_0)$.

Comment: Thank you for your time, and I'm glad that this answer has reignited my interest in mathematics after nearly three years...

Comment: you are welcome! I strongly recommend you to read deeply differential geometry and complex analysis to get your interest on fire!